# mod_rewrite won't retain $_POST vars on Apache 2.4

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

`mod_rewrite` is not passing my $_POST variables and GoDaddy have assured me it is because I need to alter my setup for Apache 2.4.

Here is my code:

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
  $q = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  if ($q[1] != "") {
    switch($q[1]) {
      case "test":
        include("test.php");
        break;
    }
  }
?>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST["submitButton"])) {
    echo "Submitted";
  } else {
    echo "Not submitted";
  }
?>
<form method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="submitButton">
</form>
```

When submitting via /test, it shows "Not submitted".
When submitting via /test.php, it shows "Submitted".

I have tried this exact setup on another host and it works fine.

What needs changing in order for it to work?

Comment: You alter the query string, so that might overwrite your post data. Try the `[QSA]` flag (query string append).

Comment: Do you start at `index.php` or `test.php`?  And with that, are you using `index.php` or `test.php` as your receiving page (aka `<form action="test.php">` for example)

Comment: @Deryck if the URL is /test it loads index.php and then includes test.php. There is no `action=` so it submits to itself, which works fine on another server but apparently not GoDaddy/Apache 2.4.

Comment: @Sumurai8 I have tried changing to `[QSA]`

Comment: Dump the contents of `$_POST` with a `<?php print_r($_POST); ?>` on your page and see what comes out both times.  I'm gonna post a possible solution here but I haven't tested it before so cross your fingers lol

Comment: May I ask why you do `?q=$1` anyway, as you parse the page using the request uri instead.

Comment: @Sumurai8 well spotted. I've now removed it, thanks.

Comment: hahah @Sumurai8 such a valid idea cant believe I didn't think of that one.  The other issue must have been too distracting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this happens is because GoDaddy's settings point the user to `missing.html` when the URL isn't a recognised file.

The fix is to ignore GoDaddy's `.htaccess` file by adding `Options -Multiviews` to your own `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this at the top of `test.php`.  Then, if that doesn't work, try it at the top of `index.php`.

```
<?php
    $rebuiltPost = array();
    parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$rebuiltPost);
    $_POST = $rebuiltPost;
?>
```

Comment: What is this witchcraft?! It works on both index.php and test.php, so I'll keep it on index.php.

Comment: hahaha sweet I'm glad I could help.  The weird thing is, this solved the problem of someone else who was using IIS 6 and not Apache.  Cheers :) here is my source btw: http://www.helicontech.com/forum/14401-RewriteRule_looses_form_POST_data.html

Comment: Excellent. Are there any downsides/vulnerabilities in using this?

Comment: I can't imagine so but you should test it against using different values in the url for query strings (`index.php?q=test&bash=full&foo=bar`) and print the `$_POST` results with `print_r($_POST);` to be sure.

Comment: Still works great. In fact, I managed to condense it to one line: `parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$_POST);`